How can I create a SQL insert table statement which inserts all records from one table into another using a python script
I am trying to create a script which will copy all data from one Postgresql table to another. My approach is to create an SQL Insert query and construct it by iterating over a  SELECT * from the table I wish to copy from. My problem is that the select resultset returns a tuple which has None instead of NULL, Booleans and Floats which are invalid types to do a ' '.join(tuple).  I want to construct an insert statement which is type sensitive (ie works with ints, floats, booleans, and null datatypes). Any Idea on how I can acheive this.
Here is my python function which uses psycopg2:
def copy_table_statement(table, create_table_columns, cur_to, cur_from):
    """
        Create insert table statement if copy data flag is True
    """
    table_name_from = table['table_name_from']
    table_name_to = table['table_name_to']
    table_schema = table['table_schema']
    sqlstring = f"SELECT * FROM  {table_schema}.{table_name_from}"
    
    # copy all data into an insert table statemen
    cur_from.execute(sqlstring)
    table_data = cur_from.fetchall()

    copy_table_sql_statement = F"INSERT INTO {table_schema}.{table_name_to} ("

    column_position = 0
    for column in create_table_columns:
        if (column_position < len(create_table_columns) - 1):
            copy_table_sql_statement = copy_table_sql_statement + " " + column['column_name'] + ", "
        else:
            copy_table_sql_statement = copy_table_sql_statement + " " + column['column_name'] + ") "
        column_position = column_position + 1

    copy_table_sql_statement = copy_table_sql_statement + "VALUES "
    print(copy_table_sql_statement)
    i = 0
    for table_datum in table_data:  
        table_datum_list = list(table_datum)
        j = 0
        for x in table_datum_list:
            if x is None:
                table_datum_list[j] = 'NULL'
            if x == True:
                table_datum_list[j] = 'True'
            if x == False:
                table_datum_list[j] = 'False'
            j = j + 1
        # if table datum is last insert values, end the sql statment with a semi-colon"""
        print(table_datum_list)
        insert_row = ' '.join(table_datum_list)
        if i < len(table_data) -1:
            copy_table_sql_statement = copy_table_sql_statement + "( " + insert_row + "), "
        else:
            copy_table_sql_statement = copy_table_sql_statement + "( " + insert_row + ");"
        i = i + 1
    return copy_table_sql_statement


And perhaps do INSERT INTO SELECT, to go even faster.

That worked. Much easier and faster. Thanks!
